# How can i move continuos enemy sprite top to bottom???

Tags: iphone

Here is some problem which I can not understand...
I want to move one enemy sprite top to bottom but enemy sprite is in different class and can not move it.

Here is code of add sprite in GameScene through Enemyscene
This is code of Enemy.m

```
#import "Enemy.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation Enemy
@synthesize theGame,newSprite,lastTimeFired,firingSpeed,fireInterval,movementSpeed,launched,hp,maxHp;

-(id)initWithGame:(GameLayer *)game
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self !=nil)
    {
        CGSize size=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
        self.theGame=game;
        self.lastTimeFired=0;
        NSLog(@"Enemy INIT ");

        int random=arc4random()%3+1;

        newSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"enemy%d.png",random]];
        newSprite.position=ccp(100,200);
        [theGame addChild:newSprite];


        switch (random) 
        {
            case 1:
                movementSpeed=5;
                fireInterval=-1;
                break;
            case 2:
                movementSpeed=10;
                fireInterval=-1;
                break;
            case 3:
                movementSpeed=7;
                fireInterval=-1;
                break;
            case 4:
                movementSpeed=3;
                fireInterval=-1;
                break;
            default:
                movementSpeed=5;
                fireInterval=-1;
                break;
        }


    }
    return self;
}
```

And I want to move this Enemy sprite into GameScene layer and here is the code
GameScene.m

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import "Hero.h"
#import "Enemy.h"
#define STARTING_LIVES 3;
@implementation GameScene
-(id) init
{
    self =[super init];
    if(self !=nil)
    {
        [self addChild:[GameLayer node]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
        [super dealloc];
}   
@end


@implementation GameLayer
-(id)init
{
    if(self=[super init])
    {

       Hero *hero=[[Hero alloc]initWithGame:self];
        Enemy *e=[[Enemy alloc]initWithGame:self];



        lastTimeEnemyLaunched=0;
        enemyInterval=20;
        lives=3;
        [self schedule:@selector(doThis)];
        NSLog(@"After Schedule");
    }
    return self;
}



-(void)doThis

{
    Enemy *e;

    [e update];

}

@end
```

Please help me i am new in cocos2d game development...
when i am run this code in simulator than it gives on error

this code gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
 -(void) update: (ccTime) dt
    {
        if( elapsed == - 1)
            elapsed = 0;
        else
            elapsed += dt;
        if( elapsed >= interval ) {
            impMethod(target, selector, elapsed);  //this code gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            elapsed = 0;
        }
    }
```

Please Help me....
Thanks

Comment: This method is in CCScheduler.m file but   EXC_BAD_ACCESS error message occur in this code.....

Comment: I think you might need to go back to basics and learn Objective-C first before you start trying to do whatever you are trying to do.